# handling checkboxes in form submission with php and db updates

Tags: php

I am using checkboxes in my form to allow the user to turn on/off certain settings. I load the form by providing the correct 'state' from values returned from the db.  They can then change these and submit the form where it is processed.  Example...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="settings[something]" '.($settings[one] == 1 ? 'value="1" checked' : 'unchecked').'/>
<input type="checkbox" name="settings[somethingelse]" '.($settings[one] == 1 ? 'value="1" checked' : 'unchecked').'/>
... and so on...
```

On the receiving end is where I can't seem to come up with a good solution to handle these.

If any of these are unchecked then the value is not even sent.  If it is checked then a value of '1'.

So, other than doing something like :

```
$something = $_POST['settings'][something']
$somethingelse = $_POST['settings'][somethingelse']
... and so on

if (!$something == 1)
{
    $something = null;
}
... and so on
```

for each value I am expecting... is there an easier way I am missing here?  I have to check each value whether it was sent or not because I am also including an option to set these values as default for multiple rows in my db - not just the one they are editing.

**EDIT :**

I took some time to think about this.  In my database I am storing these as 1 or 0 values.  Rather than checking if they were posted (set) on the receiving end of the form I am going to check if they are != to 1.  I can run down the list of values and everything that is not equal to 1 is set to 0.  This way I have a full list of all values to update in the db AND I am verifying the data integrity before inserting it into the database (1 or 0).

I am now trying to think of a quicker way to run through my 'list' to check rather than an if statement for each. Going to play around with some arrays and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes are a bit special as they are not sent to the server when they are not checked.

So the best way to check for a checkbox, is not by it's value, but simply by checking if it is set:

```
if (isset($_POST['settings']['something']))
{
  // Do what you need to do
}
else
{
  // The checkbox was not on the form (you should know that already) OR unchecked
}
```

Comment: Correct... although this situation is a bit unique in the sense that I want to verify the integrity of what was passed as well (injection check).  Since the values posted should 'only' be equal to 1 I am going check if they are not and set those values to 0.  I added some comments to my original post.